# api/auth not found for mern stack app being ported from heroku to aws ec2

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I'm deploying a mern stack app on ec2 ubuntu on aws. i'm getting 404 error api/auth not found. Front end loads up but /api is not found.

[image]

Here is the tree structure as it exists on Ubuntu server:

```
devParty/
├── client
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── webpack.config.js
├── config
│   ├── db.js
│   └── default.json
├── middleware
│   └── auth.js
├── models
│   ├── Post.js
│   ├── Profile.js
│   └── User.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── routes
│   └── api
└── server.js
```

this is my server.js which has routes defined using "app.use('api/auth..." and has the require parameter defined as "require('./routes/api/auth..."

```
const { application } = require('express')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const path = require('path')

// Connect Database
connectDB()

// Init Midddleware
// Allows us to get data in req.body on users.js
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }))

// app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API Running'))

// Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'))
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'))
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'))

// Server status assets in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static foler
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')) })
}

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

Here is a link to the project code.
[public codebase for the app](https://github.com/codereyes-1/DevSocial)

I believe the issue is in the nginx configuration for proxying requests to the api.
here is my /nginx/sites-available/default config:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # react app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /opt/devParty/client/build;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api {
    root /opt/devParty/routes/api;
    try_files $uri /api/auth.js =404;
    add_header 'Access-ControlAllow-Origin' '*';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
     }
   }
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './opt/devParty/client/public/index.html'
    })],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    externals: {
        // global app config object
        config: JSON.stringify({
        apiUrl: '/api'
        })
    }
}
```

I have tried changing api reverse proxy location to /routes, /routes/api. I also tried changing the routes defined in server.js to this but then I was getting a 502 bad gateway error:

```
app.use('/routes/api/users')
app.use('/routes/api/auth')
app.use('/routes/api/profile')
app.use('/routes/api/posts')
```

I believe I will either need to adjust the route/api folder structure but that's a whole lot of refactoring throughout the app. I think changing nginx/webpack config to find the api will be much more efficient.